# mongoose - creating schema with numeric ids as keys

Tags: typescript, mongoose

To be able to use `mongoose` , we create models with the help of a `Schema` as:

```
const instanceSchema = new Schema(
    {
        
        _mid: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        created_by: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        stages: [
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            }
        ],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

which we can use to store data such as:

```
{    
 _mid: "ONE",
created_by: "owner",
stages: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

but, what would be the `Schema` for such a data:

```
{    
     _mid: "ONE",
    created_by: "owner",
    stages: { 
      1: {
           "name": "one"
         },
      2: {    
         "name": "two"
      }  
      . 
      .    // more data   
      .
      1000: {
         "name": "oneThousand"
      }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you would be able to get that structure as it isn't valid. You could try following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288439/mongodb-how-to-insert-additional-object-into-object-collection) and see if it helps :).